# IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL with no driver referenced

Tags: windows-server-2008, bsod

I had a Windows Server 2008 R2 crash over the holidays and just got the dump file. When I looked into the dump file, I pulled out the Bug Check code `0x0000000a - IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`. However, looking in BlueScreenView there's no Driver associated with this and I'm puzzling over why this would be.

[image: Dump properties]

Looking the bug check up online, it looks like this is reporting accessing memory addresses that are restricted. Am I right in thinking that because of the lack of a driver reference, this means we are seeing something operating without a driver? As in, a very low level process?

Comment: analyze it with windbg: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: That's going to be a lot of work to set up and use, what's the value in using WinDBG vs. BlueScreenView? What can that give me above and beyond the scraping already being used?

Comment: BlueScreenView shows 99.999% crap. Windbg is the ultimate debugger

Comment: if you need help, zip the dmp file, upload the zip to OneDrive/dropbox/GoogleDrive and post a share link here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluescreen view only gives you a high level overview. In order to get in depth you will need to analyze the crash dump using Windows Debugging tools.

Analyzing a crash dump seems difficult, however it's pretty simple. This [Technet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/juanand/archive/2011/03/20/analyzing-a-crash-dump-aka-bsod.aspx) goes in depth, but it's really a 4 step process.

1. Download the [Windows Debugging tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) from the wizard only instal the WinDbg tool.
2. Launch the tool and configure the symbol path to use

> SRV*c:\SymbolsCache*=http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

1. Open the crash dump / minidump.
2. Click on the blue link that says "!analyze -v" to get more information about the events leading up to the crash.